# Is it a good idea to create dummy marker classes, just to use in generic signatures?

Tags: c#, generics, marker-interfaces

I wanted to know, if creating of marker dummy classes (with no members inside) just for the use in generic signatures is a good idea or not.

For example, think of an interface signature below:

```
public interface IBusinessValidatorFor<TContext, TEntity>
    where TContext : IContext
{
    IList<ValidationStatus> Validate (TEntity entityToValidate);
}
```

A sample concrete class that implements the above interface can be:

```
public sealed class BusinessValidatorFor<CreationContext, Customer>
    : IBusinessValidatorFor<CreationContext, Customer>
{
    public IList<ValidationStatus> Validate (Customer customerToValidate)
    {
        // Creation of customer related business validation code here.
    }
}
```

In the above concrete class definition, the class **CreationContext** (which implements the marker interface **IContext**) is a dummy class with no properties, but used for just to distinguish it from other validators for the same Customer class, but for different other contexts.

Is this approach a good idea? Are there any better design alternatives than using dummy member-less empty classes?

The purpose of the above design was to allow creating of multiple validator concrete classes for **the same entity, but for various contexts**, and use it with a Dependency Injection container.

The following code shows the usage of such validators for various contexts:

```
public sealed class CustomerController
    : Controller
{
    private readonly IBusinessValidatorFor<CreationContext, Customer>
        custCreateValidator;

    private readonly IBusinessValidatorFor<ModificationContext, Customer>
        custModifyValidator;

    public CustomerController
        (
            IBusinessValidatorFor<CreationContext, Customer> custCreateValidator,
            IBusinessValidatorFor<ModificationContext, Customer> custModifyValidator,
        )
    {
        this.custCreateValidator = custCreateValidator;
        this.custModifyValidator= custModifyValidator;
    }

    public ActionResult Create (Customer customerToCreate)
    {
        var results = this.custCreateValidator.Validate (customerToCreate);
        ...
    }

    public ActionResult Modify (Customer customerToModify)
    {
        var results = this.custModifyValidator.Validate (customerToModify);
        ...
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your time and help!

Comment: No. It's a bad idea. If your IContext interface has no behavior, that can be different between implementations, and isn't used in the validation anyway, why would you need it? It seems like you're trying to over-complicate the problem.

Comment: What does "different other contexts" mean?

Comment: Hi Mikkel, thanks for your reply. My objective was to create multiple types of validators, such as, one for the "creation context", another one for the "modification context", etc. In all such cases, I would be operating on an instance of the customer only, but the checks performed will be different, _only based on the context_ which is determined by the first generic argument, TContext.

Comment: The two concrete classes in the above case would be implementing IBusinessValidatorFor<CreationContext, Customer> and IBusinessValidatorFor<ModificationContext, Customer>. Although the entity to work on is a Customer instance, the activities performed are different in the above two cases.

Comment: @DineshMuciliathJayadevan: Who calls these validators? You haven't posted any code, related to use-cases.

Comment: In an MVC implementation, the CustomerController for handling customer might want to apply a rule for the "creation context", or for the "modification context" depending on needs inside the "Create ()" or "Modify ()" action methods. If I can dependency-inject these two different types of validators for different contexts, my MVC controller would be able to use them as appropriate.

Comment: @Dennis - I have modified the post to include a usage scenario. In the MVC controller in the example, the dependencies will be injected using a Dependency Injection container.

Comment: It seems as you're creating these to enhance readability. You shouldn't. Let your validators express what you're trying to do

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - My purpose is to have different "types" (as the generic argument changes, the type also changes), and make it possible to have different concrete types, all operating on the same entity ("Customer" in the example). The dependency injection container will look at them as different types, and hence will pick and inject them as and when necessary, based on the needs of the consumers.

If I did not use the TContext generic argument, I would be making multiple concrete classes, all implementing the same interface and DI will inject only the last registered concrete type.

Comment: Why last? Cant it resolve by registering a name for each concrete type?

Comment: If I don't use TContext, the interface will be IBusinessValidatorFor<Customer>. If I have more than one concrete classes implementing the above interface (one for creation, another one for modification, etc.), the DI container (for example, StructureMap) would come across with multiple concrete classes implementing the same interface. Thus, when DI container is requested for a concrete instance, it would return the last registered concrete instance (i.e., the one for create, or for modification). It won't be able to distinguish the context and give. That's why the first generic argument.

Comment: For example, if you have CustomerCreateValidator : IBusinessValidatorFor<Customer>, and CustomerModifyValidator : IBusinessValidatorFor<Customer>, and if you register them against IBusinessValidatorFor<Customer>, the DI container would give only the last registered type (i.e., whichever one of the above). Whereas, if you have the classes as CustomerCreateValidator : IBusinessValidatorFor<CreationContext, Customer>, and CustomerModifyValidator : IBusinessValidatorFor<ModifyContxt, Customer>, the types are different now, and DI will register them as concrete classes of two different types.